# Are there specific rules for dual-wielding/two-weapon attacks in Infinity RPG?

Tags: combat, two-weapon-fighting, infinity-rpg

I recently started playing Corvus Belli's Infinity RPG (based on their tabletop miniatures game IP).  I was looking at the weapon sizes and trying to see if there were any rules in the Core book or Player's Guide covering using 2 pistols or 2 1-handed knives and making attacks with both at the same time, as other RPG systems might cover (dual-wielding or two-weapon attacks in other systems).  Nothing stood out to me in the indexes, item or combat sections covering this.  Is there a rules section that I have overlooked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## There are not specific rules for dual-wielding in the Player's Guide

There don't appear to be an rules that explicitly deal with dual wielding in the Players Guide. As best I can tell, dual wielding is mentioned exactly once, in the *Quick Draw* talent.

There are some general rules that could provide some mechanics to back up a narrative depiction of dual wielding, but they would work the same with a single weapon. Your options are:

1. Spending 2 Momentum (or Heat) to perform a *Swift Action*, which will allow you make a second Standard Action at increased difficulty.
2. Spending an Infinity Point to take a *Bonus Action*, which allows to you make a second Standard Action (not at increased difficulty).
3. This one is very loose, even from a narrative perspective, but using the *Return Fire* reaction.

A non-RAW solution for ranged weapons would be to treat the second pistol as granting +1 Burst to the first pistol. Since Burst simulates sending more bullets downrange, and that's what the second pistol allows.